# Не могу пользоваться Git в Idea

Tags: git, intellij-idea

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]Создал репозиторий через VCS/Import into Version Control/Create Git Repository
Сделал пару комитов, поигрался и удалил на сайте Github все репозитории. Теперь пытаясь создать новый репозиторий так же как и первый, он ничего не создает. Висят две ветки в логах, и удалить их нельзя, Delete не активна. Как избавиться от этого всего, чтобы я мог работать с новым репозиторием, без этих старых следов?

Answer (score 2):

Удалите `.git` в корне проекта и перезапустите IDE.

Comment: Не нашел такого ни в одном проекте, в папке IntelliJ IDEA, и в папках C:/Users/ Возможно ли, что словил глюк и нужно переустанавливать idea?

Comment: Нет. В никсах все файлы и директории, начинающиеся на точку считаются скрытыми. В винде, насколько я помню, скрытие устроено иначе, но скорее всего вы не нашли эту папку именно из за того что она скрытая. Либо не там смотрели. Я же сказал, она лежит в корне проекта. Не в C:/Users/ и не где-то ещё. Как вариант, вы можете просто удалить этот проект целиком и создать новый.

Comment: На самом деле, вы можете найти такую папку и в другом месте, но в таком случае это будет совсем другой репозиторий! :)

Comment: Верно, открыл скрытые файлы и нашел такую папку. Она была просто в диске E:/ , а папка со всеми проектами была в E:/IntelliJ IDEA Project/ удалил всю папку и да, все очистилось, спасибо большое. Буду дальше экспериментировать, что бы в дальнейшем знать, из за чего появилась такая ошибка! Сделал git init и папка .git теперь появилась в самом проекте.